# Gnuplot_i.hpp C++ interface plot local variables instead of a file

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I've been using Gnuplot_I.hpp c++ interface that lets you use gnuplot inside a c++ program. It works well except I can't seem to control plot symbols, color, and some other important plot features. The code snippet below illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>       //io format setw(space)
#include "spline.h"
#include "gnuplot_i.hpp" //Gnuplot class
//
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   //
   vector<double> X(5), Y(5);
   X[0]=0.1;
   X[1]=0.4;
   X[2]=1.2;
   X[3]=1.8;
   X[4]=2.0;
   Y[0]=0.1;
   Y[1]=0.7;
   Y[2]=0.6;
   Y[3]=1.1;
   Y[4]=0.9;

//demoFile two colums 6 spaces apart
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        demoFile << std::setw(6) << X[i];
        demoFile << std::setw(6) << Y[i];
        demoFile << '\n';
   }
   demoFile.close();
//
   Gnuplot g1("");
   //
   g1.reset_plot();
   cout << endl << endl << "*** user-defined lists of points (x,y)" << endl;
   g1.set_grid();
   g1.set_pointsize(4.0);
   g1.cmd("set term wxt font ',14';set xtics font 'Times-Roman, 14'; \
           set ytics font 'Times-Roman, 14'");
//
   g1.cmd("plot 'plotfile.txt' with points pointtype 7 pointsize 2 lc 'red'");
   g1.set_style("points").plot_xy(X,Y,"Original");
```

The last plot commands lets you plot X,Y local vector variables, but I can't set the symbol or color of the points. There is a set_style command but this doesn't work to set some important plot features. You can use the cmd() command as above which allows the "with points pointtype 7 pointsize 2 lc 'red'" string that does allow these important features. The problem is the command string doesn't seem to have a way of incorporating local vector variables X and Y. The command string only recognizes a file argument which forces you to output to file before plotting. I've tried to format gprintf and sprintf strings to recognize local variables X and Y have have not been successful. Is there anyone out there that has solved this problem?

Comment: I didn't know gnuplot_i.hpp before, is it from https://github.com/tttamaki/gnuplot-cpp?

Comment: Could you please post code which compiles? What is `"splines.h"`, what is `demofile`? Are they needed to reproduce the problem? Where does `main()` end?

Comment: spines.h calculates a cubic spline for the X,Y points given. It is not relevant to the question. You can google it. The spirit of the question is about the gnuplot interface, whether there is a way to plot data already in memory in the c++ program. For example the cmd() method interprets single quotes ( ' ' ) as a file name embedded in the cmd string, is there some preface like $X that is interpreted as a local  variable. Can data be plotted without first writing a file is the question.

Answer (score 0):

The plot_xy() routine in gnuplot_i.hpp writes the X and Y vectors to a temp file and then tells gnuplot to plot that file.  You can do exactly the same except issue a full gnuplot plot command via `g1.cmd` with all the style specifications you like, as you show in your script.  So what is the question exactly?

Except from plot_xy():

```
std::string name = create_tmpfile(tmp);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    tmp << x[i] << " " << y[i] << std::endl;
tmp.flush();
tmp.close();    
plotfile_xy(name, 1, 2, title);
```